# Why get require('fs') is undefined in r.js

Tags: node.js, requirejs, r.js

I want append some string from file use `fs.readSyncFile()`, but I get a undefined.

r.js -o build.js

```js
({
  appDir: ".",
  baseUrl: './assets/js',
  dir: 'build',
  modules: [
    {name: 'init'}
  ],
  paths: {
    'init': 'app/init'
  },
  onBuildRead: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
    if(moduleName == 'init') {
      console.log('--------------' + require('fs'));//undefined
    }
    return contents.replace("'/assets/js/main.js',", "");
  },
})
```

Comment: Please also describe how you run this file in your build chain. Which utility is being told to interpret it, using which command/what syntax?

Comment: What if you put `var fs = require("fs");` outside of the `onBuildRead` function and reference `fs` from inside?

Comment: @voidpigeon `Error: Build file build.js is malformed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`. I put `var fs = require('fs')` to first line.